# Inviting email contacts to my business page

Tags: facebook-pages

I do not have a personal account on Facebook but created a page for my business. When I attempted to invite my contact list from my personal email account by hitting "invite contacts" I continue to get the message to make sure my personal email password is not the same as my Facebook password, which it is not.  I have tried this multiple times. How can I resolve this?
Do I have to have a personal page to invite others to my business page?